# Was ist die deutsche Übersetzung für "whatever" in diesem Comedy-Kontext

Tags: english-to-german

Es geht um diesen kurzen [Clip](https://youtu.be/791lBGA3XXk?t=257)

In dem Aussschnitt aus dem Interview mit Gordon Ramsay, Sofia Vergara und Jay Leno wird Sofia unverschämterweise gefragt wie viel Gewicht sie zugenommen hat und nach einigem hin und her antwortet sie "whatever". Das Publikum lacht daraufhin.

Was ist an der Antwort lustig? Wenn ich die deutsche Übersetzung "was auch immer" in diesen Kontext einsetze, erscheint mir die Antwort nicht sonderlich witzig. Was wäre daher eine entsprechende Übersetzung?

Comment: Zu bewerten, was an einer Interview-Antwort in englischer Sprache witzig sein soll, ist nicht Gegenstand von German StackExchange.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  Es geht in der Frage aber doch gar nicht darum, was im Englischen daran witzig sein könnte, sondern eher darum, wie man den genuin nicht witzigen Dialogausschnitt ins Deutsche übertragen würde (sähe man dazu denn eine Veranlassung).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Die Kernfrage war doch aber, was an der Antwort *whatever* lustig sei; auch die deutsche Übersetzung scheine dem OP nicht witzig. Selbst wenn es sich doch nur um ein Übersetzungsgesuch für das Wort *whatever* handelte, wäre die Frage off-topic.

Comment: Mir ging es darum eine angemessene Übersetzung zu finden. Ich hatte das Gefühl, dass ich die Bedeutung von "whatever" in diesem Kontext nicht korrekt verstanden hatte bzw "wie auch immer"  in diesem Kontext nicht die optimale Übersetzung wäre.

Comment: Ich find's interessant, subjektive Sachen wie Humor als objektiv zu proklamieren. Ich finde das whatever an der Stelle lustig. Oder verbietet das die deutsche Sprachpolizei?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Der Dialog ist nicht an sich witzig, und das "whatever" ist es auch nicht. Das Publikum lacht, weil es mit der Erwartungshaltung im Studio sitzt, dass Repliken der Interviewten witzig sein werden.

Eine gewisse Rolle mag spielen, dass die Interviewte mit "whaterver" im Grunde den Interviewer (halb verdeckt) grob abbürstet, was in solchen Studiointerviews zwischen Prominenten ja nicht üblich ist.

Die Frage ist somit: Mit welchem Ausdruck könnte eine deutschsprachige Interviewte den zudringlichen Interviewer in so einer Situation (halb verdeckt) grob abbürsten?

Vorschläge:

- Ach, keine Ahnung.
- Ist doch wurscht.
- Du hast aber auch Fragen!
- Ach komm jetzt!
- Mir doch schnurz!
- Schnurzpiepe
- Gna-gna-gna
- Das geht dich einen feuchten Kehricht an. (Das ist natürlich nicht mehr "halb verdeckt grob" sondern direkt grob.)
- Frag nicht! (Wobei das fast schon wieder witzig wäre, jedenfalls für Leute, die Salcia Landmanns Sammlung jüdischer Witze kennen.)

Die Liste lässt sich aber beliebig erweitern, da es kaum auf den lexikalischen Inhalt ankommt sondern eher auf die zum Ausdruck gebrachte Ablehnung des Themas und der Haltung des Interviewers.

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort. Natürlich ist Witzigkeit subjektiv aber deine Vorschläge passen aufjedenfall besser als "wie auch immer". Ich habe noch eine weitere Möglichkeit gefunden: "Egal!" - wobei das Ausrufezeichen finde ich wichtig ist. Das ähnelt meinem Sprachempfinden nach deinem letzten Vorschläg, auch wenn ich Salcia Landmann nicht kenne.

Comment: @v.tralala  "Frag nicht!" hat - für mich jedenfalls, aber so auch bei S. Landmann - die Bedeutung "Es ist so negativ, dass ich darüber nicht sprechen will." Das passt m.E. nicht besonders gut in das o.g. Interview mit der ja immerhin nach wie vor nicht übergewichtigen Interviewten.

Comment: Das spiegelt überhaupt nicht den Eindruck wieder, den ich da kriege. Da wird nicht "grob abgebürstet", das ganze ist ein Necken auf freundlicher Basis.

Comment: Es könnte hier mitschwingen, dass "whatever" in gewissem Kontext auch "so viel wie möglich" bedeuten kann. Das wäre allenfalls eine Stilblüte und hier eigentlich nicht gemeint. Zudem so plausiebel wie "wieviel? alles!", was bei Gewichtszunahme dort wie hier nicht passt, aber ich habe schon wierderes gelesen. Ich mein, die Interviews sind eben nicht ganz natürlich ;) Bin kein Mutterspracheler, also nur wage Vermutung.

Answer (score 5):

Ich stimme den anderen Antworten nicht zu. Der Moderator rät zunächst "2 pounds" also (1kg) und sie sagt nein. Dann rät er "10 pounds" (5kg) was die richtige Zahl zu sein scheint. Anstatt zu lügen und nein zu sagen, oder anstatt es zu bestätigen ("yes, that's right") sagt sie "whatever". So deutet sie an spielerisch eingeschnappt an, dass es stimmt, was den lustigen Effekt erzielt.

Eine deutsche Übersetzung könnte wie folgt sein:

> Leno: Und? Wieviel hast du denn zugenommen?
>   Sofia: Was ist das denn für eine Frage?
>   Leno: Also? Wieviel?
>   Sofia: Na, das sag ich dir doch nicht!
>   Leno: 1 Kilo?
>   Sofia: Neee
>   Leno: 5 Kilo?
>   Sofia: Reden wir über was anderes ;)

Comment: So hatte ich es noch nicht betrachtet und erklärt die Komik besser. Danke!

Comment: Der letzte Satz könnte z.B. auch gut "Reden wir von was anderem" sein.

Comment: "2 Kilo" muss nach eigenen Angaben oben "Ein Kilo" heissen. Und ihr "Nooo" heisst ja so viel wie: "also hör mal", was bei 1 Kilo mehr Sinn ergibt( "Neheee!").. Der Dialog ist sonst sehr gut getroffen!, musste gleich noch ein zweites Mal lachen, diesmal auf Deutsch.

Comment: Ob sie "eingeschnappt spielt" oder wirklich angepisst ist ob der dummen Frage und es nur professionell überspielt kann nur sie beantworten. Ich geh eher von letzterem aus.

Comment: Da sie viel Spaß zu haben scheint im Interview gerne ich von ersterem aus. Gerade auch dann, wenn man andere Videos mit ihr kennt, verstärkt das den Eindruck.

Answer (score 3):

Hier hat Jay Leno durch sein charmantes, aber eskalierendes Nachfragen (two pounds? - Nooo! - ten pounds? ...) Vergara in die Ecke gedrängt. Sie reagiert aber sehr gekonnt und witzig auf die Zahlenreihe.

Vielleicht:

**"Wieviel auch immer!"**

(statt "**Was** auch immer")

Sie gesteht zwar ein bisschen, aber J. Leno kann nicht mehr weiterfragen. Das "whatever" bezieht sich auf die 2, 10 oder x Pfund.

---

Sie wollte ja durchaus was sagen. Der Pizza-Urlaub mit Fotos war sowieso eigentlich ihr Thema.

> Leno: Zwei Pfund?
>
> Sofia: Neeein! Ich mein...(wird unterbrochen)
>
> Leno: Zehn Pfund?
>
> Sofia (überlegt): *Hat eh kein' Zweck*!

"Mit Dir kann man nicht reden" und "jetzt ist es sowieso raus" (die "10 Pfund zugenommen" -- auch wenn's etwas drunter war, jedenfalls viiiel mehr als 2)

Answer (score 2):

In diesem Kontext scheint mir "das ist doch egal" die beste Übersetzung zu sein (vgl. Pucks Antwort). Dass Sofia Vergara "not amused" über Jay Lenos Mutmaßungen ist, wird deutlich. Insofern könnten auch "darüber will ich nicht sprechen" oder "lassen Sie es jetzt gut sein" passen. Doch wie auch immer das "whatever" zu verstehen ist: Wirklich witzig ist die Antwort nicht. Doch wer weiß, ob das Publikum wirklich gelacht hat oder ob nur eine Tonkonserve eingespielt wurde (im amerikanischen Fernsehen nicht unüblich)? Falls das Lachen echt war, galt es vielleicht der Gesamtsituation und der penetranten Art von  Jay Leno.

Wenn man sich übrigens den Clip weiter anhört, stellt man fest, dass Jay Leno ihr sagt, im amerikanischen Fernsehen müsse man sich solchen Fragen stellen. Sofia Vergaras Antwort: "A couple of pounds, it's okay, I was on vacation".

Answer (score 0):

Mein spontaner Eindruck der Szene ist so.

Zuerst hat die Frau gute Laune, dann als der Moderator sie fragt ob sie 10 Pfund zugenommen hat, wechselt sie plötzlich den Ton und sagt nur noch knapp "whatever". Sie möchte offensichtlich auf einmal das Thema wechseln.

Vielleicht hat sie sich durch die Frage in irgendeiner Art ertappt gefühlt? Vielleicht kommt die Zahl der Realität näher als ihr lieb ist? Aus meiner Sicht ist das der Grund, warum das Publikum lacht.

Dabei geht es nicht genau darum **was** sie sagt, sondern **wie** sie es sagt.

Man könnte das also einfach als ebenso knappe Antwort übersetzen, wie etwa nur "ach, egal", oder "anderes Thema". Wobei auch der Wechsel in der Stimmung wichtig ist, um die Situation nachzubilden.